# nearZeroVar() generates unexpected integer(0)

Tags: r, variance

It's unclear to me why this generates integer(0). The olive data is numeric and contains variance.

```
# install.packages("pgmm")
> library(pgmm)
> data(olive)
> nearZeroVar(olive)
integer(0)
```

Comment: I can't replicate this problem.  Can you give a sample of the data? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `nearZeroVar` will return which predictors have 0 (or near 0) variance. There are none in `olive` so it returns an empty vector (`integer(0)`).

You can see the `freqRatio` and `percentUnique` with `saveMetrics`.

```
nearZeroVar(olive, saveMetrics = TRUE)
#>             freqRatio percentUnique zeroVar   nzv
#> Region       2.139073     0.5244755   FALSE FALSE
#> Area         3.169231     1.5734266   FALSE FALSE
#> Palmitic     1.555556    54.0209790   FALSE FALSE
#> Palmitoleic  1.454545    30.5944056   FALSE FALSE
#> Stearic      1.000000    24.1258741   FALSE FALSE
#> Oleic        1.142857    68.0069930   FALSE FALSE
#> Linoleic     2.571429    60.1398601   FALSE FALSE
#> Linolenic    1.058824     7.8671329   FALSE FALSE
#> Arachidic    1.269231    13.2867133   FALSE FALSE
#> Eicosenoic   1.597222     7.6923077   FALSE FALSE
```